# Remove duplicate values from a defaultdict python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary.

```
a = {6323: [169635, 169635, 169635], 6326: [169634,169634,169634,169634,169634,169634,169638,169638,169638,169638], 6425: [169636,169636,169636,169639,169639,169640]}
```

How do I remove the duplicate values for each key in dictionary a? And make the values become [value, occurrences]?

The output should be

```
b = {6323: [(169635, 3)], 6326: [(169634, 6), (19638, 4)], 6425: [(169636, 3), (19639, 2), (19640, 1)]}.
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I pasted the dict.items() output so they weren't dictionaries. I corrected it now.

Also edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Those are sets with tuples (and impossible with mutable list objects in the values), not dictionaries. Dictionaries have colons between the keys and the values, not commas and parentheses.

Comment: Those are sets, not dictionaries...

Comment: Apart from that you are missing a `)` somewhere

Comment: And even if we assumed these are dictionaries, how are the key-value pairs in `a` related to the expected output in `c`? I can *guess* that you want the values in the lists in `b` to draw in the values from `a`, but please be explicit.

Comment: Then there are the edge cases; what happens if a key is missing in `a`? What should happen with the order in the `b` lists if there is more than one unique value? What should happen with the values of `a` when there are multiple unique values in a list from `b`? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest iterating on the items and for each value build a defaultdict incrementing the occurence. Then convert that indo your tuple list (with the item method) and drop that in the output dictionnary.

```
b = {}
for k,v in a.items():
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in v:
        d[i] += 1
    b[k] = d.items()
```